# Best practices for bower components

Tags: gulp, bower

So I am just getting started writing front-end code using tools like gulp, bower, and polymer.

I installed polymer and some of the material design components via bower.

Is best practices to reference files from the bower_component folder, ex:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

or should I use gulp to copy whats needed to another folder structure.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) is most probably the package you're looking for.

It will search through the *bower_components* folder and inject all dependency files into your *index.html*

Usage in HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- endbower -->
</body>
```

And in *gulp* you simply need to:

```
gulp.src('index.html')
  .pipe(wiredep({
    optional: 'configuration',
    goes: 'here'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
```

Answer (score -1):

create `.bowerrc` ,

should look like :

```
ex:.bowerrc

{
 "directory:"folder/path"
}

do:bower install
```